# Поменять метод кнопки на POST

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, yii2

есть кнопка -  обратный звонок - сайт на фреймворке yii2, нужно что бы при запросе работал post запрос, сейчас срабатывает get по этому выдаёт ошибку - METHOD NOT ALLOWED. THIS URL CAN ONLY HANDLE THE FOLLOWING REQUEST METHODS: POST.
Кто знает подскажите куда смотреть, что почитать, не понимаю где описать или изменить логику метода кнопки

```
<a class="callback ajax-popup-link" href="/callback">обратный звонок</a>
```

Comment: @Alban, не существует такого атрибута в ссылке, ссылка только GET

Comment: отлавливать событие клика по ссылке, когда срабатывает то отправляешь post-запрос на /callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click', '.ajax-popup-link', function(e){

e.preventDefault();

var href = this.href;

            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                url: href,
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    // error
                },
                success: function(data, textStatus){
                    //success
                }
            });

            return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Например формой:

```
<form method="POST" action="/callback">
    <button type="submit">обратный звонок</button>
</form>
```

Или перехватывать в js клик по кнопке и делать ajax post запрос.

Comment: не работает, уже писал так

Comment: Идея в том что бы вписать domain.com/callback и вывелась форма
вот так, а выводит 405 ошибку
если просто на кнопку нажать то она работает

Comment: @OlegArtyukh, тогда у вас вопрос неправильный, к кнопке это вообще не относится. Надо разрешить в php GET для этой страницы.

Comment: Нет, так страницы не существует, при нажатии кнопки вылазит форма, короче клиент хочет что бы при вводе урла тоже вылазила форма, нужно не разрешить get запрос, а поменять его на post

Comment: @OlegArtyukh, теперь я совсем ничего не понял.

Comment: http://chicardi.com
сверху слева кнопка обратный звонок при нажатии работает,
урл её http://chicardi.com/callback,
если ввести урл в адресную строку выдает 405
задача - исправить 405 ошибку

Comment: чтобы введя chicardi.com/callback перекинуло на главную и с формой? Надо разрешить в php GET для этой страницы. Направить ее на глауную с какой-нибуть пометкой, и н аглавной тригать клик по кнопке

Comment: ок, спасибо) буду пробовать